# Why can't I get react-quill input to reset after post is submitted

Tags: reactjs, react-quill

I'm using react-quill to give my users more options to post on the forums in the way they want to. My input component looks like this...

```
<ReactQuill
    theme='snow'
    defaultValue={value}
    onChange={value => setComment(value)}
    modules={{
        toolbar: [
            ['bold', 'italic', 'underline','strike', 'blockquote', 'code-block'],
            [{'list': 'ordered'}, {'list': 'bullet'}],
            [{ 'script': 'sub'}, { 'script': 'super' }],
            ['link', 'image']
        ],
    }}
    placeholder={'Write your post here...'}
/>
```

After the input is submitted and then saved on the backend successfully, I want to reset the input to '', so that the react-quill input box is empty. To do this I'm using...

```
// on success
if(res.status === 200){
    setComment('')
    setCommentLoading(false)
}
```

When this is triggered, nothing about the input changes, I've tried using console.log(comment) to see what the value of 'comment' is and it shows as being an empty string like I want it to, however the react-quill input box still shows the message that was posted. Does anyone know what is causing this and what I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I would try to use **value** prop for this one since it is a controlled component.

```
<ReactQuill
  theme='snow'
  value={comment}
  onChange={value => setComment(value)}
  ...
/>
```

Comment: I can't because (for some reason I don't understand) the spacebar doesn't work properly with ReactQuill when I use 'value', but it does work when I use 'defaultValue'

Comment: Nevermind, ignore my last message I managed to get it to work again using 'value' by setting the react-quill editor to have the white-space: pre; value in css

Comment: that's great :)

Comment: Having a similar problem now with the enter key when trying to go on the next line. The enter key has to be pressed twice if my cursor is at the last character of the input box, but if the cursor is in the middle, the enter key works fine.